# Single object detection keras

Tags: python, keras, object-detection, training-data

I want to make a system that recognizes a single object using keras. In my case I will be detecting car wheels. How do I train my system just for 1 object? I did classification task before using cats and dogs, but now its a completely different task. Do I still "classify", with class 0= wheels, class = 1 non wheels(just random images of anything)? How do I do following steps in this problem?
1) Train system for 1 object
2) Detect object(sliding window or heatmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is a so-called binary classification. 
Make sure, that your final layer has got only one neuron (e.g. for Sequential model model.add(Dense(1, ... other parameters ... ))) and use the binary_crossentropy as loss function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply! So I will have 2 classes , one with wheels, other non-wheels? Can you tell me why there is only one neuron at the final layer as oppose 2, since there are 2 classes??

Comment: You are right. I think you understood your problem well now.
You could also use two neurons in the end for the binary classification. 
Have a look at: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207049/neural-network-for-binary-classification-use-1-or-2-output-neurons
 
You can implement both and look which performs better (e.g. note overfitting).
The choice is yours. Give it a try ;)